# Drag and drop in a list view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-listview

I have little experience with android.

I'm trying to make a drag+drop aware list view because various other solutions don't do what the client wants, and this project is likely going to have me making a lot of other "fun" draggy-droppy-swipey things like this for a while.

The requirements are simple: User can drag a thing from a list out and into something else using the android drag+drop API (if you call it that). It works as long as said things aren't in a list view or something that intercepts long presses or whatever.

Here's what isn't working so far:

```
package blah;

import android.os.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View*;
import android.widget.*;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static class ItemView extends TextView
    {
        public int position;

        public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context,attrs);
        }
    }

    private class _Adapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity _activity;

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            // TEST: Make it go
            return 16;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convert, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this._activity.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
                    );

            ItemView itemView = (ItemView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_view,parent,false);

             // TEST: Just display positions
            itemView.setText(Integer.toString(position));

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new _ItemClickListener());

            itemView.setOnDragListener(new _ItemDragListener());

            itemView.position = position;

            return itemView;
        };

        public _Adapter(Activity activity)
        {
            this._activity = activity;
        }
    }

    private class _ItemDragListener implements OnDragListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event)
        {
            ItemView targetItemView = (ItemView)view;

            int action = event.getAction();

            switch(action){
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                {
                    // not really sure which is which here, since nothing works
                    ItemView sourceItemView = (ItemView)event.getLocalState();

                    Log.d("DERP",
                            "DROPPED " + Integer.toString(sourceItemView.position) +
                            " ONTO " + Integer.toString(targetItemView.position)
                            );
                }break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class _ItemClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            ItemView itemView = (ItemView)view;
            Log.d("DERP", Integer.toString(itemView.position) + " WAS CLICKED");

            // nothing happens here
            view.startDrag(
                ClipData.newPlainText("",""),
                new View.DragShadowBuilder(view),
                view,
                0
                );
        }

        public _ItemClickListener()
        {
        }
    }

    private Activity _activity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this._activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ListView listView = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        listView.setAdapter(new _Adapter(this._activity));

        return listView;
    }
}
```

My intuition tells me that making a drag+drop list should be simpler than this, given the "breadth" of features supported by the android UI. However, this is also Java, so I'm not expecting straightforward answers.

Comment: There is a library call [drag-sort listview](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). You should check it out.